# Entity Framework NullReferenceException when accessing lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Windows Forms and I'm just learning Entity Framework and I have a question: I created a `Customer` class with a list type of `Item` and with Entity Framework I created a table for it. But when I try to get the list from it, I get a NullReference exception.

This are my classes:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PassWord { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the method I created to get the customer list based on the `ID` of the customer. I get the Id from the login and it works just fine:

```
public List<Item> CustomerItems()
{
    using var context = new CustomerContext();

    var customer= context.Customers.Find(Id);
    var items = customer.Items;
    return items;
}
```

I wanted to use this method to update the datagrid and add new items to the list.

I added some entries to the `Item` table but they don't show up in the datagrid.

Comment: You don't have enough code here to explain your issue. 
First of all, Find(Id) would normally only return 1 item, not a list. 
But if it does, and your list is null, something isn't mapped correctly. 
It would normally return an empty list if there are no items. 
not a null.

You have to track down via debugging ( Debug mode) where precisely it happens, or at least also include the stack trace of your exception if you want help.

Comment: I am using find to get the customer that has the corresponding ID and Im accessing its ıtem list with that if you need another codeblock I can provide it for you.

Comment: Replace List with ICollection and make this property virtual.

Comment: How are your items associated back to a Customer? In a one-to-many relationship, the Items table would need a Customer Id column (CustomerId, or Customer_Id) which you would need to populate for each item you add.

Comment: Add include in your query.
`context.Customers.Include(x => x.Items).find(Id)`

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Comment: @Den Isn't `Find` a method on `DbSet`/`DbContext`?

Comment: @Guru, he said that this method work just fine... i think this is an extentions method...
Edit => in EF6 not in core the mehtod find exists [see this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/ef6/querying/#finding-an-entity-by-primary-key)

Comment: @Den 1) I was not stating that the OP code will not work (and the fact that it does work does not prove that your code will work) 2) There is no proof that OP is using EF6 and not Core (if it is relevant in this context) 3) `Find` exists in EF Core 4) the link you have provided that `Find` is available for type returned by `Include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) section of the docs for options how to load linked data.

Also in this case you can just use proper query returning only needed data. For example:

```cs
var items = context.Customers
    .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Items)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

In the code snippet presented above a `NullReferenceException`may occur in the access to `Items` in the expression `customer.Items` when `customer` is `null`. The code should be modified to handle the `null` value, e.g.

`var items = (customer == null) ? new List<Item>() : customer.Items;`

Comment: The OP specifically mention that customer id is correct. You should reflect on your answer the case where it's not customer that's null but it's item property.

Comment: The answer is based on the code above and assumes that the exception occurs in this code. A null Items property would not cause a NullReference exception since Items is not used in this code, only returned.

Comment: ı am using CustomerItems method to get the Items that the customer has and I am trying to add a new Item to the returned list. thats where it gives me the null exception.

Comment: Okey, so the exception occurs _outside_ the code shown above? Then my answer is not valid. From the stack trace you see where the problem is located. Perhaps you should add this code to the question. There is probably nothing wrong with CustomerItems().